# Which maximal amount of nodes can subnet with mask 255.255.255.248 contain?

Tags: subnet

**Which maximal amount of nodes can subnet with mask 255.255.255.248 contain?** Kindly explain how it can be calculated

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to binary:

```
11111111111111111111111111111000
```

Invert it:

```
00000000000000000000000000000111
```

Convert to decimal:

```
7
```

Subtract 1:

```
6
```